# A little help with the passive form

Tags: grammar, particle-に, passive-voice

> さて本日より貴様らに新たな命令が下されるわけだが
>   "Now then, today I’m going to give you new orders"

I don’t get why the 貴様 is being targeted by the action. Shouldn’t they be doing the action instead?

For example,

> お前たちに蹴られた
>   I was kicked by you guys

The に here indicates that お前たち is the one doing the action and the subject of the sentence (which is omitted) is the one receiving the action.

Let’s try a simpler sentence

> お前に命令が下される
>   (私は)お前に命令 が下される

Shouldn’t this mean “I am given orders by you.”? But according to my initial sentence this would come out as “I am giving you orders”.

Does the に here indicate “to you” instead of “by you”? Or does the が somehow influences something?

Also if I were to rephrase this one

> お前たちに足が蹴られる

Would this come out as "I am kicking your legs"?

Once again, how does the に function here?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37097/5010 Some verbs take ～に in the active version, where it usually corresponds to "to ～". This type of に is left unchanged in the passive version, and it still means "to ～". You can use によって, the more explicit version meaning "by", to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence "私が、お前に命令を下す" has two objects of direct object and indirect object. 命令を is a direct object and お前に is a indirect object in this sentence. If you want to change a sentence like this to passive form, I think you can make two ways.

For example, in the case of 私が、お前に命令を下す(I give you orders"). One passive form is in the case that direct object is a subject like 命令が、お前に私によって下される(Orders are given you by me).

Another is in the case that indirect object is a subject like お前が、私によって命令を下される(You are given orders by me).

お前が、私を蹴った(You kicked me) has one object, so the passive form is only 私が、お前に(よって)蹴られた(I was kicked by you).

That is to say, if you want to change the sentence which has two objects to passive form, it needs "に" which indicates a target in the case that direct object is a subject.

In addition, “I am given orders by you" is translated 私が、お前によって命令を下される. And お前が私に命令を下す(You give me orders), 命令が、私にお前によって下される(Orders are given me by you).