# ～になった versus ～された

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentences.

- 警察官が免許を没収した。The police officer seized (my) license.
- 免許が警察官に没収された。(My) license was confiscated by the police officer.

If I want to use 「免許が没収になった。」, how can I insert 警察官 into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [～によって](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37097/5010) and say 免許が警察官によって没収になった. 免許が警察官に没収になった would also be understood, but many people would say this is clumsy due to the duplication of に.

Answer (score 2):

You can put 警察官　in the beginning.  警察官により免許が没収になった。. It sounds bit awkward but I think it works in the same way.