# Function of に here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-に, passive-voice

Found this sentence:

> 両親が死んだというのに、悲しもうとすらしない俺**に**向けられる目が。クズみたいなニート**に**向けられる目、敵意。軽蔑。

That に in 「悲しもうとすらしない俺に向けられる目が」is acting as the indirect object or is it marking the doer? Since it's a passive sentence.

Answer (score 2):

This ～に is marking the target/destination of the 目. ～に used in a passive construction does not necessarily mark the doer (agent).

> 俺**に**向けられる目
> stares cast **to** me
> <sub>(not "stares cast **by** me")</sub>

Now you may be wondering if に in a passive sentence can be ambiguous. The answer is yes. See the following questions:

- [Confusing 届ける　受身 form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54988/5010)
- [Particle に in passive sentences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87051/5010)
- [The meaning of ”あれは魔術師に与えられた祝福”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76392/5010) (see my answer)
- [How does the passive form work here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38739/5010)

Comment: I still don't understand why 向ける is passive here. Will 俺に向ける目 also work? Can you write 俺に向けられる目 as a non-passive sentence?「Xが目を俺に向ける」とか

Comment: @JimmyYang XをYに向ける means "to direct X to Y". Naturally, its passive version is XがYに向けられる ("X is directed to Y"), and its relativized version is Yに向けられるX ("X which is directed to Y"). 俺に向ける目 is "stares [someone] casts to me", which is grammatical but defeats the main purpose of passive voice here. Do you remember "suffering passive"?