# What is the meaning of 詠{よ}む in the following sentence? この俳句に詠{よ}まれている季節はいつでしょうか。

Tags: meaning

I provide the full paragraph for context. The sentence in question is stressed in bold:

> 下に挙げたのは、アメリカの大学が日本語の授業で作った俳句の例です。
> ?>
>
> > 静かだね。　雪の音しか　聞こえない
> >
> > 子が母が　呼び合うごとく　蝉のなく
> >
> > 秋の歌　落ちた木の葉に　書いてある
> >
> > 春の午後　ホームレスたち　昼寝して
>
> どうですか。それぞれの俳句から、どんな情景が浮かんできますか。作った人のどんな気持ちが感じられますか。**この俳句に詠{よ}まれている季節はいつでしょうか**。

---

Now, 詠{よ}む can mean two different things according to [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A9%A0%E3%82%80):

1. To compose or write a Japanese poem.
2. To use [something] as the theme of a poem.

I tried to look up the word in monolingual dictionaries but couldn't find the second meaning there. I am not sure if the usage in this sentence is 1 or 2:

1. この俳句に詠{よ}まれている季節はいつでしょうか。 The season written in these Haikus, when is it?
2. この俳句に詠{よ}まれている季節はいつでしょうか。 The season being used as a theme in these Haikus, when is it?

In terms of grammar, 2 is fine. However, if the real meaning here is 1, the sentence sounds awkward to me. I'd rather use が than に :

この俳句が詠まれている季節はいつでしょうか。The season in which these poems were written, when is it?

To summarize,

- What is the exact meaning of 詠む in this context, 1, 2 or another
  meaning?
- If it is 1, how does に work in the original sentence then?

Comment: [大辞林](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/大辞林/prefix/詠む) is clearer about the second sense than others.

Comment: If it helps to think about and remember the word, consider the English sense of _"to read into [a text]"_.  This doesn't include the sense of 歌を作る that we have in the Japanese, but it does include the sense of considering the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transitive verb 詠む can take two kinds of direct objects:

1. a type/format of poetry: 俳句を詠む, 和歌を詠む
2. a theme of a poem: 喜びを(俳句に)詠む, 美しい景色を(和歌に)詠む

Not all monolingual dictionaries may explain both patterns explicitly since 詠む is not a very basic verb, but the second usage is fairly common. 明鏡国語辞典 clearly explains the second usage:

> 【使い方】 ～ヲに〈結果〉をとる。「山桜［感動］を歌に詠む」のように、～ヲに〈対象〉を、～ニに〈結果〉をとる言い方もある。

In your sentence, the object of 詠む is 季節:

> [この作者は]季節を詠んでいる
>  ↓  (convert to passive voice)
> 季節が詠まれている
>  ↓  (relativize)
> 詠まれている季節

So it's used in the second sense. This に is a location/destination marker ("**in(to)** these haiku"), not a subject marker in a passive construction ("written/used **by** these haiku"). The に-marked argument in a passive sentence is not necessary the subject. See [Function of に here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/88787/5010)