# a question about に in the paragragh below

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, ambiguous-relative-clauses

> 私たちは働くとき、何らかの社会的役割を担（注1）っていて、その役割に応じた結果が求められます。そして、期待に応えたときに得られるものが報酬（注2）や自身の成長です。要するに、私たちは働くとき「得る」前に求められているものを「与える」ことになります。仕事の本質（注3）は得ることではなく、**自分に求められているものを人に与える**、すなわち「人の役に立つ」ことなのです。

I am confused by structure of the bold sentence. I think the sentence wants to deliver the meaning that "We give others something that we are required for by others", but I don't know why it is に that is used after 自分 instead of が, since the structure is 受け身の形.
I guess maybe 求められている is not 受け身 の 求める but 尊敬語 of 求める, which I think is not very likely.

Answer (score 2):

This unfortunately is an inherent ambiguity of Japanese relative clauses when combined with some passive verbs. For example, 彼に求められていること can mean either "things required **of** him" and "things required **by** him" depending on the context, and you have to choose the correct interpretation from the context. In this context, 自分に求められているもの means "required of us", not "required by us" (using "us" as the translation of 自分).

> **自分に**求められているものを人に与える。
> We give others things that are required **of us**.

自分**へ**求められているもの would unambiguously mean "things required of us". 自分**から**求められているもの ans 自分**によって**求められているもの would unambiguously mean "things required by us".

See also:

- [Confusing 届ける　受身 form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54988/5010)
- [The meaning of ”あれは魔術師に与えられた祝福”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76392/5010)
- [How does the passive form work here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38739/5010)
- [Particle に in passive sentences? あいつから、例の本が彼女に渡された](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87051/5010)

Comment: things required by him  is not plausible in this paragraph given the context,so the only possibility is that 求められている in this paragraph is  尊敬語'ている form of 求める

Comment: @CN.hitori No, forget honorifics now. There is no need to pay respect to someone in an article like this. 求める is a trivalant verb. Just as you can say AがBにCを渡す or AがBにCを紹介する, you can say AがBにCを求める (A requires C of B; A requests C from B). With this in mind, please read the links.

Comment: I guess the complete verson of sentence is ものが人に自分に求められている,is my guess right?

Comment: @CN.hitori Close, but you have to say [もの]が[人]によって自分に求められている. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37097/5010